# Change Field index to not_analyzed through hive external table

Tags: elasticsearch, hive, kibana

I am indexing data to ES through hive by using the query :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE json2 ( time_id_1 STRING, acnt_nm) 
STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES('es.resource' = 'es_testing/test', 'es.nodes' = 'xxx');

insert overwrite table json2 select time_id_1 , acnt_nm from table_x;
```

I want my string column `acnt_nm` to be "not analyzed".
I found out there is a way of doing this through Mapping API by setting the "index": "not_analyzed"

I know this can be done through explicit mapping. But that is very cumbersome as i will have to do that every time before indexing any new data.
But can i do the same through the hive external table creation command ?

Or maybe just edit the index to "not_analyzed" for all the indexed data. It is not possible for me to change it individually for each id as i have too many of them.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need not-analyzed at hive side? Actually creation script does not work without any type. You can set string at least.
I think you can change the mapping of es_testing index and this performs the mapping on each individual document in that index.